# how to make a phone call on click automatically without redirecting to dialer pad in ionic framework?

Tags: android, ionic-framework

```
<ion-content>
<div class="item item-button-right ng-click="CallingTel({{user.phone1}})">
<h2><b>Mobile No.</b></h2>
9999999999
<button class="button button-positive">
<i class="icon ion-ios-telephone" ></i></button>
</div></ion-content>
```

The above fragment of code is from HTML page which has Phone call button.

The below fragment of code explains about functionality of Phone calling functionality.

```
angular.module('starter.PhoneController',[])
.controller('PhoneCtrl',function($state,$scope,$rootScope)
              {
                $rootScope.home = true;
                $rootScope.telnumber1 = " 9999999999";
                $scope.CallingTel = function(tel) {
                    window.location.href = 'tel:'+ $rootScope.telnumber1;
                  }
             });
```

I have even added the "`<access origin="tel:*" launch-external="yes" />`" code in `config.xml`. Can anyone give me the solution on how to automatically bypass call without displaying the dialer pad?

Comment: Try these sample code from this  [link](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/making-phone-call-from-app-href-tel-123/1968/14) it worked for me....if not i will upload a sample project for you

Answer (score 0):

```
<access origin="tel:*" launch-external="yes" />
```

You need to add this line in **two places** , **project_name/config.xml** and **project_name/platforms/android/res/xml/config.xml**.